# How to fix Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, docker, python-2.7, setuptools, setuptools-scm

I inherited a docker containerized setup. Previous engineers maintaining it are long gone. When I try to build the image, it is complaining during installation of one of the packages specified in requirements.txt

requirements.txt contents:

```
setuptools==40.6.3
pip==1.5.4
paramiko==2.4.2
scp==0.13.0
timeout_decorator==0.4.1
requests==2.21.0
pylint==1.9.4
jsonschema==2.6.0
six==1.11.0
dnslib==0.9.10
SQLAlchemy==1.3.5
psycopg2==2.8.3
future==0.17.1
tenacity
```

Error seen during installation:

```
  Collecting lazy-object-proxy (from astroid<2.0,>=1.6->pylint==1.9.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/3e/7c80e8536b9d5eb66e784fff4c359adf9e55b37460fd6928192256ba71f2/lazy-object-proxy-1.7.0.tar.gz (42kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-JMyxNe/lazy-object-proxy/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
          distclass=BinaryDistribution,
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
          replace_conflicting=True,
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
          replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
          return cmd.easy_install(req)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in easy_install
          return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 724, in install_item
          dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 909, in install_eggs
          return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1177, in build_and_install
          self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1163, in run_setup
          run_setup(setup_script, args)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
          raise
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
          saved_exc.resume()
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
          six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
          yield saved
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 44, in _execfile
          code = compile(script, filename, 'exec')
        File "/tmp/easy_install-bKS9kl/setuptools_scm-7.0.5/setup.py", line 20
          def scm_version() -> str:
                            ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
[91mCommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JMyxNe/lazy-object-proxy/
```

I am confused where exactly to fix this issue. I know that it is using python 2.7 which is not supported but bringing entire project to python 3+ is not ideal at this time. I believed the packages and their versions below should work with python 2.7 as it has been all this time until I deleted the image. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Try adding `setuptools-stm=5.0.2` to `requirements.txt`.

---

At least some of the project is attempting to use Python 3.

```py
File "/tmp/easy_install-bKS9kl/setuptools_scm-7.0.5/setup.py", line 20
  def scm_version() -> str:
```

This line, `def scm_version() -> str:` is using [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) introduced in Python 3.5.

It looks like this is coming from `setuptools-scm`. 7.0.5 is the latest version.

I think this is happening as `pylint` is being installed, based on the info on the first line of your traceback, as an automatic dependency installation. You could try pinning `setuptools-stm=5.0.2` as a requirement, since that is the last version that supports Python 2.

It *might* work. If it does, there's no guarantee that something else won't be broken. You may need to pin other requirements (like `tenacity`, which has no pinned version).

That's my best suggestion!